# How to exclude classes from scanning with CDI-unit?

Tags: cdi, cdi-unit

I am running tests with CDI-unit runner and want some classes to be excluded (because they act on CDI events). I tried beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee">
    <scan>
        <exclude name="com.mypackage.**"/>
    </scan> 

</beans>
```

but CDI-unit seems to be ignoring it. So what is the correct way to exclude the classes with CDI-unit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may provide an alternative of the class you want to exclude, so that the alternative test class is used instead. With CDI Unit you turn on your alternative with `@ActivatedAlternatives` on your tests, or globally with `@ProducesAlternative` on your test producer. See more here: http://jglue.org/cdi-unit-user-guide/#alternatives

AFAIK, CDI Unit does not directly support exclusion of beans. But in most cases using alternatives is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me and even \@Produces \@Mock was enough :)